# SQL - Using placeholders to retrieve rows that are LIKE the placeholder

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, placeholder

I have 3 tables;

**Drinks**

[image: Restaurant]

**Food**

[image: Food]

**Drinks**

[image: Drinks]

Drink tbl is joined to Restaurant via RestID, Food tbl is joined to Restaurant via RestID

I am trying to create a query that does the following;

- User inputs food they would like (E.g. Burger)
- User inputs drink they would like (E.g. Guinness)
- The query returns the restaurant that serves both of these items

I am trying to create a query that checks if inputted drink is LIKE text in both `drinkvariety` & `drinkname` columns in Drinks table, and that checks if inputted food is LIKE text in both `foodcategory` and `foodname` in Food table. Only when the query inputted placeholders are LIKE either column, the restaurant will return as result.

I have attempted to create this query using this, but the syntax must be wrong as it does not return as desired;

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.restname
FROM restaurants r
JOIN food f ON f.restid = r.restid
JOIN drinks d ON d.restid = r.restid
WHERE f.foodcategory LIKE '%?%'
  AND d.drinkvariety LIKE '%?%'
```

Note: the above only checks 1 column per table at the moment. I am aware, but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and what about vegetarian section?

Comment: I'm sorry... what? What about a vegetarian section, apologies I am confused...

Answer (score 1):

You must not put the `?` parameter placeholders inside a quoted SQL string literals in your query. Parameters are an alternative to using string literals.

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.restname
FROM restaurants r
JOIN food f ON f.restid = r.restid
JOIN drinks d ON d.restid = r.restid
WHERE f.foodcategory LIKE ?
AND d.drinkvariety LIKE ?
```

Then I would pass parameters as strings, after prepending and appending '%' to the string variable in my app.

Alternative: Prepend and append the wildcard in SQL, but keep the parameter placeholder separate.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.restname
FROM restaurants r
JOIN food f ON f.restid = r.restid
JOIN drinks d ON d.restid = r.restid
WHERE f.foodcategory LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
AND d.drinkvariety LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

With either solution, the placeholder still must not be inside an SQL string literal.

Otherwise how would you ever search for a literal question mark in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
SELECT r.restname
FROM restaurants r
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM food f 
              WHERE f.restid = r.restid AND
                     f.foodcategory LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM drinks d
              WHERE d.restid = r.restid AND
                    d.drinkcategory LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
             ) ;
```